# For better SEO: What to use for html title tag: "|" vs ":" vs "-"?

Tags: seo

I'm asking this because I don't know if it matters for better SEO or not.

```
MyWebsite.com - Current Page Title
MyWebsite.com : Current Page Title
MyWebsite.com :: Current Page Title
MyWebsite.com | Current Page Title
```

Currently I'm using the first option from above. I'm just wondering, 1) which one better for good SEO?

2) Also, which is better for good SEO: Do we keep the site name in the beginning (like above) or the end of the title tag (like below)?

```
Current Page Title - MyWebsite.com
Current Page Title : MyWebsite.com
Current Page Title :: MyWebsite.com
Current Page Title | MyWebsite.com
```

I've noticed that Google use something like this:

```
searchterm - Google Search
```

Comment: Nice question, but probably off-topic.

Comment: Just use normal punctuation. Don't use characters because they look pretty.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/14399-new-poll-whats-your-favorite-page-title-separator/, posted yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're all noise, and neither will make a difference. Does your domain name even belong in the title?

> Make sure that each page on your site has a useful and descriptive page title (contained within the title tags. If a title tag is missing, or if the same title tag is used for many different pages, Google may use other text we find on the page.

[Create descriptive page titles](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35624#3)

Answer (score 2):

All identical as far as Google is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

On a practical note, having the domain first may push too many characters off to the right, making it difficult to distinguish different pages from the same site in bookmark lists, or history. I prefer to put the page title first (truncated, if necessary) then the site name, except on the home page, which should just get the site name, I reckon.